# How to take screenshot and share in mobile using phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm trying to take screenshot of current page and share via facebook, whats app, instagram, twitter etc., using phonegap. But was unable to do that properly.
I tried out this code but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
function report() {
    let region = document.querySelector("body"); // whole screen
    html2canvas(region, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            let pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            let img = document.querySelector(".screen");
            img.src = pngUrl; // pngUrl contains screenshot graphics data in url form

            window.plugins.socialsharing.share(img.src);

            // here you can allow user to set bug-region
            // and send it with 'pngUrl' to server
       },
   });
}
```

Comment: What does mean *it doesn't work*? Does it throw any error? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Have you try this plugin : https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot ?